Focus Up/Down not working in Android Studio with FrameLayouts inside ConstraintLayout with Leanback
I have an activity that has a constraint layout with an EditText element, and then two frameLayouts where I'm adding a RowSupportFragment and a VerticalSupportGridFragment programmatically based on an API call. I am getting the data and it is being displayed on the screen. However, you can't navigate up/down. I don't know why it's not working properly.
Here is my layout XML file:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/searchLayout"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_input"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:hint="Enter search term here"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:nextFocusDown="@id/searchChannelLayout"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:privateImeOptions="horizontalAlignment=center"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchTextView"
        />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemCountChannels"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/searchChannelLayout"
            />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/searchChannelLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nextFocusUp="@id/searchEditText"
                android:nextFocusDown="@id/searchVideoLayout"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchEditText"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/searchVideoTitle"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/searchVideoTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Videos"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchChannelLayout"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/searchVideoLayout"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemCountVideos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/searchVideoTitle"
            />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/searchVideoLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:nextFocusUp="@id/searchChannelLayout"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/itemCountVideos"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Here is my Activity kotlin file:
class SearchActivity: AppCompatActivity(), SearchView {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivitySearchBinding
    private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()
    private val presenter = SearchPresenter()
    private var fManager: FragmentManager? = null
    private var fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction? = null

    private var channelList: List<SearchResultsChannelHitData>? = emptyList()
    private var videoList: List<SearchResultsVideoHitData>? = emptyList()
    private var channelFragment: SearchChannelRowFragment? = null
    private var videoFragment: SearchVideoGridFragment? = null

    override fun onCreate(bundle: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(bundle)

        presenter.attachMvpView(this)
        fManager = supportFragmentManager

        binding = ActivitySearchBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setupEditTextListeners(binding.searchEditText)

        channelFragment = SearchChannelRowFragment(
            onItemClick = ::onChannelItemClick,
            onItemSelect = ::onChannelItemSelect
        )
        videoFragment = SearchVideoGridFragment(
            onItemClick = ::onVideoItemClick,
            onItemSelect = ::onVideoItemSelect
        )

        fragmentTransaction = fManager?.beginTransaction()
        channelFragment?.results = channelList ?: emptyList()
        videoFragment?.results = videoList ?: emptyList()
        fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.searchChannelLayout, channelFragment!!)
        fragmentTransaction?.add(R.id.searchVideoLayout, videoFragment!!)
        fragmentTransaction?.commit()

        binding.searchEditText.requestFocus()
    }

    private fun showKeyboard(view: View) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }

    private fun setupEditTextListeners(et: EditText) {
        et.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                showKeyboard(view)
            }
        }
        et.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                if (s.toString().length > 2) {
                    val searchBody = SearchRequestBody(q = s.toString())
                    Log.d("SearchActivity", "Search query: ${searchBody.q}")
                    presenter.getSearchResultsData(searchBody)
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            }
        })
    }

    override fun getMvpContext(): Context = this

    override fun showSearchResults(searchResults: SearchResultsData) {
        channelList = searchResults.channel?.hits
        videoList = searchResults.videos?.hits

        channelFragment?.results = channelList ?: emptyList()
        videoFragment?.results = videoList ?: emptyList()
        Log.d("SearchActivity", "channelList: ${channelList?.size} | videoList: ${videoList?.size}")
        Log.d("SearchActivity", "channelFragment: ${channelFragment?.results?.size} | videoFragment: ${videoFragment?.results?.size}")
        binding.searchVideoTitle.visibility = if (videoFragment?.results?.size!! > 0) View.VISIBLE else View.INVISIBLE
        Log.d("SearchActivity", "videoTitle visibility: ${binding.searchVideoTitle.visibility}")
    }

    private fun onChannelItemClick(videoUrl: String?, videoTitle: String?, imageURL: String?) {
        Log.d("onHostItemClick pos: ", videoTitle.toString())
        val hostDataObject: HostData = HostData()
        hostDataObject.title = videoTitle
        hostDataObject.imageUrl = imageURL
        //HostDetailActivity.launchActivity(this, videoUrl, videoTitle, imageURL)
    }

    private fun onChannelItemSelect(itemPosition: Int?, totalSize: Int?) {
        Log.d("onChannelItemSelect pos: ", itemPosition.toString())
        //this.itemPosition = itemPosition;
        binding.itemCountChannels.text = "${itemPosition?.plus(1)} of $totalSize"
    }

    private fun onVideoItemClick(itemPosition: Int?, item: SearchResultsVideoHitData) {
        if (item.productId.isNullOrEmpty().not()) {
            PaidMediaActivity.launchActivity(this, item.productId, item.productId, item.document?.thumbnailUrl)
        }
        else {
            val videoUrl = item.document?.hlsUrl ?: item.document?.videoPlaybackUrl
            ExoPlayerActivity.launchActivity(this, videoUrl, item.title, item.document?.thumbnailUrl, itemPosition ?: 0)
        }
    }

    private fun onVideoItemSelect(itemPosition: Int?, item: SearchResultsVideoHitData?, totalSize: Int?) {
        //this.itemPosition = itemPosition;
        binding.itemCountVideos.text = "${itemPosition?.plus(1)} of $totalSize"
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        disposables.clear()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
        Log.e("SearchActivity", "Error: ${throwable.message}")
        errorView(throwable.message)
    }

    private fun errorView(message: String? = null) {
        //binding.progressbar.visibility = android.view.View.GONE
        Toast.makeText(this, message ?: "There was an error with your request. Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        //finish()
    }


    private fun transitionToPlayer(mediaDetails: MediaDetailsData, holdView: Boolean = false) {
        val itemDetails: AllVideosData = AllVideosData()
        itemDetails.videoUrl = mediaDetails.mediaUrl ?: mediaDetails.trailerUrl
        itemDetails.title = mediaDetails.productTitle
        itemDetails.teaserText = mediaDetails.productDescription

        itemDetails.let {
            ExoPlayerActivity.launchActivity(this, it.videoUrl, it.title, it.teaserText, 0)
            if (!holdView) finish()
        }
    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        // Custom Key events here
        return when (event?.keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> {
                Log.d("KeyEvent", "KEYCODE_BACK")
                finish()
                true
            }

            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER -> {
                Log.d("KeyEvent", "KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER")
                true
            }

            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN -> {
                if (binding.searchChannelLayout.hasFocus()) {
                    Log.d("KeyEvent", "KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN | channels have focus")
                    binding.searchVideoLayout.rootView.requestFocus()
                    true
                } else if (binding.searchEditText.hasFocus()) {
                    binding.searchChannelLayout.requestFocus()
                    true
                }
                else {
                    false
                }
            }

            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP -> {
                if (binding.searchVideoLayout.hasFocus()) {
                    channelFragment?.view?.requestFocus()
                    true
                } else if (binding.searchChannelLayout.hasFocus()) {
                    binding.searchEditText.requestFocus()
                    true
                }
                else {
                    false
                }
            }

            else -> {
                super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun launchActivity(
            activity: Activity,
        ) {
            val intent = Intent(activity, SearchActivity::class.java)
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(
                activity,
                intent,
                null
            )
        }
    }
}

Here is my RowSupportFragment:
class SearchChannelRowFragment(
    var onItemClick: (String?, String?, String?) -> Unit?,
    var onItemSelect: (Int, Int) -> Unit?
): RowsSupportFragment(), OnItemViewSelectedListener, OnItemViewClickedListener {

    private var channelList: List<SearchResultsChannelHitData>? = null

    private var mainAdapter: ArrayObjectAdapter? = null
    private var channelListAdapter: ArrayObjectAdapter? = null

    private var firstItem: SearchChannelItemCardPresenter? = null
    private var firstItemPos: Int? = 0

    var results: List<SearchResultsChannelHitData> by Delegates.observable(emptyList()){ _, oldValue, newValue ->
        if (oldValue != newValue){
            Log.d("SearchVideoGridFragment", "results changed: $oldValue | $newValue")
            results = newValue
            displayData()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val aa = CustomListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE, false)
        aa.shadowEnabled = false
        aa.selectEffectEnabled = false
        mainAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(aa)

        setAlignment(60)

        setOnItemViewSelectedListener { itemViewHolder, item, rowViewHolder, row ->
            Log.d("Item", "Item: $item")
            val listRow = row as ListRow

            val currentRowAdapter = listRow.adapter as ArrayObjectAdapter
            val itemPos = currentRowAdapter.indexOf(item)
            if (currentRowAdapter == channelListAdapter) {
                firstItemPos = itemPos
                //Log.d("itemPos", "ItemPos: $itemPos")
            }
            onItemSelect.invoke(itemPos, listRow.adapter?.size() ?: 0)
        }
        setOnItemViewClickedListener { itemViewHolder, item, rowViewHolder, row ->
            Log.d("setOnClickListener", "setOnClickListener $item")
            val listRow = row as ListRow
            val currentRowAdapter = listRow.adapter as ArrayObjectAdapter
            val itemPos = currentRowAdapter.indexOf(item)
            if (item is HostData){
                Log.d("setOnClickListener", "setOnClickListener: ${item.title}")
                // Convert SearchResultsChannelHitData to HostData to pass
                // to HostDetailActivity.launchActivity
                activity?.let { HostDetailActivity.launchActivity(it, item, itemPos ) }
            }else if (item is AbsoluteRowData){
                onItemClick.invoke(item.videoUrl, item.title, item.imageUrl)
            }else if (item is RecentlyAddedRowData){
                Log.e("recent item", "Item")
                onItemClick.invoke(item.mediaUrl, item.title, item.imageUrl)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mainAdapter?.clear()
        clearData()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        mainAdapter?.clear()
        clearData()
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(itemViewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder?, item: Any?, rowViewHolder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder?, row: Row?) {
        val position: Int? = mainAdapter?.indexOf(item)
        if (item is SearchResultsChannelHitData){
            onItemSelect.invoke(position?:0, mainAdapter?.size() ?: 0)
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(
        itemViewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder?,
        item: Any?,
        rowViewHolder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder?,
        row: Row?
    ) {
        Log.d("SearchChannelRowFragment", "onItemClicked")
        if (item is SearchResultsVideoHitData && item.productId.isNullOrEmpty().not()){
            Log.d("ProductID", "ProductID: ${item.productId}")
            activity?.let { PaidMediaActivity.launchActivity(it,null, item.productId, item.document?.thumbnailUrl) }
        }else if (item is AbsoluteRowData){
            onItemClick.invoke(item.videoUrl, item.title, item.imageUrl)
        }else if (item is RecentlyAddedRowData){
            Log.e("recent item", "Item")
            onItemClick.invoke(item.mediaUrl, item.title, item.imageUrl)
        }
    }

    private fun displayData(){
        Log.d("SearchChannelRowFragment", "displayData run ${results.size}")
        // We need to mutate results into HostData objects
        var hostDataList = mutableListOf<HostData>()
        for (result in results) {
            val hostData = HostData()
            hostData.title = result.title
            hostData.teaserText = ""
            hostData.nid = result.document?.externalId
            hostData.imageUrl = result.document?.imageUrl
            hostDataList.add(hostData)
        }
        mainAdapter?.clear()
        channelListAdapter?.clear()
        channelListAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(SearchChannelItemCardPresenter(requireContext()))
        channelListAdapter?.addAll(0 ,hostDataList)

        if (channelListAdapter?.size() != 0){
            mainAdapter?.add(ListRow(HeaderItem("Channels"), channelListAdapter))
        }

        /*  if(absoluteItemList.isNullOrEmpty().not()) {
                val headerFeaturedItem = HeaderItem("Recent Clips")
                absoluteItemAdapter?.addAll(0, absoluteItemList)
                if (absoluteItemAdapter?.size() != 0){
                    mainAdapter?.add(ListRow(headerFeaturedItem, absoluteItemAdapter))
                }
            }
        */

        adapter = mainAdapter

        if (firstItem == null){
            firstItem = channelListAdapter?.getPresenter(0) as? SearchChannelItemCardPresenter
        }
    }

    private fun clearData(){
        channelList = emptyList()
        mainAdapter?.clear()
    }
}

Here is my VerticalSupportGridFragment:
class SearchVideoGridFragment(
    val onItemClick: (index: Int?, item: SearchResultsVideoHitData) -> Unit,
    val onItemSelect: (index: Int?, item: SearchResultsVideoHitData, size: Int?) -> Unit
): VerticalGridSupportFragment(), OnItemViewSelectedListener,
    OnItemViewClickedListener {

    private var mainAdapter: ArrayObjectAdapter? = null

    private var firstItem: SearchVideoItemCardPresenter? = null
    private val ZOOM_FACTOR: Int = FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE
    private val COLUMNS = 6
    private val deviceWidth = DisplayMetrics().widthPixels
    private val cellWidth = deviceWidth / COLUMNS
    private val cellHeight = cellWidth * 9 / 16

    var results: List<SearchResultsVideoHitData> by Delegates.observable(emptyList()){ _, oldValue, newValue ->
        if (oldValue != newValue){
            Log.d("SearchVideoGridFragment", "results changed")
            displayData()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d("SearchVideoGridFragment", "onCreate")
        setupAdapter()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.d("SearchVideoGridFragment", "onCreateView")
        val view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        applyConstraints(view)
        return view
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        clearData()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        clearData()
    }

    private fun applyConstraints(view: View?) {
        Log.d("SearchVideoGridFragment", "applyConstraints: $view")
    }

    private fun setupAdapter() {
        val videoGridPresenter =
            CustomVerticalGridPresenter(ZOOM_FACTOR, false, 100, 1, 0,0)
        videoGridPresenter.numberOfColumns = COLUMNS
        videoGridPresenter.shadowEnabled = false
        val itemDecoration = VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(200)
        videoGridPresenter.gridView?.post {
            videoGridPresenter.gridView?.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration)
        }

        setOnItemViewSelectedListener(this)
        onItemViewClickedListener = this
        gridPresenter = videoGridPresenter

        val sideInfoCardPresenter =
            SearchVideoItemCardPresenter(requireActivity())
        mainAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(sideInfoCardPresenter)
        adapter = mainAdapter
        applyConstraints(videoGridPresenter.gridView?.rootView)
    }

    private fun displayData(){
        mainAdapter?.clear()
        mainAdapter?.addAll(0, results)

        if (firstItem == null){
            firstItem = mainAdapter?.getPresenter(0) as SearchVideoItemCardPresenter
        }
    }

    private fun clearData(){
        mainAdapter?.clear()
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(
        itemViewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder?,
        item: Any?,
        rowViewHolder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder?,
        row: Row?
    ) {
        Log.d("SearchVideoGridFragment", "onItemSelected")
        val position: Int? = mainAdapter?.indexOf(item)
        if (item is SearchResultsVideoHitData){
            onItemSelect.invoke(position, item, mainAdapter?.size()?:0)
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(
        itemViewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder?,
        item: Any?,
        rowViewHolder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder?,
        row: Row?
    ) {
        Log.d("SearchVideoGridFragment", "onItemClicked")
        val position: Int? = mainAdapter?.indexOf(item)
        if (item is SearchResultsVideoHitData){
            onItemClick.invoke(position, item)
        } else {
            Log.d("SearchVideoGridFragment", "item is: "+ item!!::class.simpleName)
        }
    }

}

Since the rowFragment is one row, I can manually handle the focus between the row and the searchEditText, but I really don't want to do it that way.
